# Android glClear cause glError 1286

Tags: android, opengl-es, decode, framebuffer

I am trying to do some video things on android with OpenglES,MediaCodec,SurfaceTexture,and a bunch of other things. First I decode frames from video as GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture. Then I render this to framebuffer. Here is the code:

```
    checkGlError("before renderTexture");

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mCameraFbo.frameId());
    checkGlError("renderTexture 1");

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, mInputImageWidth, mInputImageHeight);
    checkGlError("renderTexture 2");

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    checkGlError("renderTexture 3");

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    checkGlError("renderTexture 4");

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    if (texid != OpenGlUtils.NO_TEXTURE) {
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texid);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "inputImageTexture"), 1);
    }

    mTriangleVertices.position(0);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTriangleVertices);

    mGLTextureBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mGLTextureBuffer);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(0);
```

It Crashes in My Nexus 5X and Nexus 6P, at this line "GLES20.glClear", with glError 1286. But It's just fine on other older devices,such as Nexus 5 and Xiaomi Note.

I've checked framebuffer state with "glCheckFramebufferStatus",I'm pretty sure it is fine.

**Device info:**

```
Nexus 5X, Android7.1.1
```

**GPU info:**

```
vendor  : Qualcomm

renderer: Adreno (TM) 418

version : OpenGL ES 3.2 V@145.0 (GIT@If5818605d9)
```

Anybody have idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out why...I create framebuffer with an EGL Context, use it with another,